# How to find an element in a List<T> where name is the same and its time is the same or at least similar?

Tags: c#, steam

I am currently working on a project which uses two methods, one method returns the most accurate player list on a server with the duration the player was on the server, and the second method utilizes a different method which returns a player list with less accuracy and no time, but with an additional value which I need that other method doesn't have. To put it in simple terms:

Method 1:

```cs
List<PlayerObjectMethod1> playerListMethod1 = GetPlayersFromServerMethod1(serverIp, serverPort);
```

The class method 1:

```cs
public string Name { get; set; }
public float Duration { get; set; }
```

Method 2:

```cs
List<PlayerObjectMethod2> playersFromMethod2 = new List<PlayerObjectMethod2>();
```

The class method 1:

```cs
public string Name { get; set; }
public string SpecialValue { get; set; }
public string CustomDuration { get; set; }
```

Now as you can see the *method 2* doesn't officially return duration, however this method is running every 15 seconds, so in theory, I could attach 15 seconds to each player every time it runs.

More background:

The parent method runs on a timer every 15seconds. There are 5 servers in total for one server (time in between specific server gets scanned) is around 18 seconds, as such each player on each call can be 18 seconds. I need to get an accurate player for that specific value. Two comparisons I want to do:

1. If a players name is not 123, only compare the name to get a specific value.

```cs
if(playerListMethod1[i].Name != "123") {
   var index = playersFromMethod2.FindIndex(x => x==playerListMethod1[i].Name)
   playersFromMethod2[index].IsOnline = True;
   playersFromMethod2[index].Duration = playerListMethod1[i].Duration;
}
```

And now if it is 123 I need to find it by name and duration. However, the issue I have is how to upkeep that second list and add 15 seconds to all the players with name 123. As before I would use a list to store old player list value and just clear it and `AddRange` of the new one.

Example:

```cs
serverNotfPlayerListOld[server.Name].Clear();
serverNotfPlayerListOld[server.Name].AddRange(playersFromMethod2);
```

So I basically need an idea on how to do this, would I first fill the method2 with players, then check non 123 players, then check 123 players, and then add 15 seconds to the 123 players and at some point the list would get accurate?

**Edit**:

As mentioned before there are two different methods (two different sources) one gives name and duration, the other name and player id. As such, I need to somehow merge that data together. To do that I thought I could add my own duration for the second method because it's being run every 45 seconds. The current new code I have:

Example of the addition solution

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        HashSet<A> a = new HashSet<A>()
        {
            // add random values
            new A { Id = "josh", Value = 60, },
            new A { Id = "tom", Value = 60, },
            new A { Id = "koven", Value = 120, },
            new A { Id = "123", Value = 240, },
        };
        HashSet<A> b = new HashSet<A>()
        {
            // add random values (some with Id's from a)
            new A { Id = "tom", Value = 10, },
            new A { Id = "4123", Value = 10, },
            new A { Id = "koven", Value = 65, },
            new A { Id = "5552", Value = 60, },
            new A { Id = "123", Value = 45, },
        };
        IEnumerable<A> c = IdJoin(a, b);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (A element in c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{element.Id}: {element.Value}");
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Count: {i}");
        Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<A> IdJoin(IEnumerable<A> a, IEnumerable<A> b)
    {
        Dictionary<string, A> dictionary = a.ToDictionary(i => i.Id);
        foreach (A element in b)
        {
            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(element.Id, out A sameId))
            {
                if (element.Id == "123")
                {
                    sameId.Value += element.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    sameId.Value += 45;
                }
            }
            else {
                dictionary.Add(element.Id, element);
            }
        }
        return dictionary.Values;
    }
}
public class A
{
    public string Id;
    public float Value;
}
```

Issue with this is that if it reads by only name it will bug out as multiple players can have 123. Which is why I need comparison method which gets by name and duration (of few minutes differences) in those two lists and I need help with that. Another example:

Two 123 players join the game. One list has values `[name:123, duration:240],[name:123, duration:60]` the other has `[name:123, player:7548, customDuration: 225], [name:123, player:7555, customDuration: 90]`

I need to get which player is which.

Comment: I don't think you are going to get a solid response. I have read through this 3 times and i still have no idea what you want. It's a very abstract question and without having inside knowledge on how your server works or even what you are trying to accomplish is going to hinder any responses. I would think through your question and re-ask with way more context.

Comment: Edited the question, is it more understandable right now?

Comment: To find something concrete there must be something unique that distinguish your data. In a case of List<T> you may search against some unique property in class T or combination of properties. You may also override Object.Equals operator in class T. Your question is more about business logic not programming issue.

Comment: If there is no unique id in both of your lists, there is no way to guaranty correct association of elements. there is always a chance that you'll get not only a couple of players with the same name, but also with the same duration: `[name:123, duration:240],[name:123, duration:**240**]`

Comment: As @x00 pointed out there is no way to guarantee correct association if you have identical names. What you could do is force names to be different, or associate a unique playerID to each player.

Comment: Yea I understand that, but I don't know any other way to make it work. For the first method:

I can only get name, the duration, for second name and id. I could create custom ids to both, but then I would need to assign it on request and still match them up somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming Id and Value combination makes unique value:

```
class Program
{
    static List<A> firstList;
    static List<A> secondList;
    static List<A> resultList;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Fill firstList, secondList with data <your server methodes>

        resultList = new List<A>();

        foreach (var item in firstList)
        {
            var match = secondList.Find(a => a.Equals(item));
            if (match != null)
            {
                if (item.Id == "123")
                {
                    item.Value += match.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Value += 45;
                }
            }
            resultList.Add(item);
        }

        resultList.AddRange(secondList.Except(firstList));
    }
}

public class A
{
    public string Id;
    public float Value;

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        if ((obj == null) || !GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var a = (A)obj;
            return (Id == a.Id) && (Value == a.Value);
        }
    }
}
```